# How would you find and cultivate specific forms of algae?

Tags: microbiology, ecology

Knowing how simple and efficient it is to grow algae, I started wondering how a person would specifically isolate and grow different strands of algae. Say I walk to the closest body of water and took a sample of water. How would I prepare it so that I only got a specific strain of algae, say a green algae?